# Where is the official place to store settings of a python module?

Tags: python, file, io, settings, python-module

My python module needs to save some configuration files into a disk, is there a standard convention on where to save your module configuration files? one that you won't run into a permission error.

Answer (score 2):

You can store these configuration file where ever you want (as long as your python script have the write permission to this directory and no process prevent it from writing to this directory (is not locked by other process)), as long as your module can reach them for parsing or for import if they are a python files.

what are the options:

1. store them in the same module directory, and import/parse them.
2. store them in deferent directory and in your python module change the `os.path` with `os.chdir(path)` to this dir for parsing.
3. store them in `dir_x` and provide the `dir_x path` to your python script via command line args with `sys.argv[1]`. or with argparse!

Comment: I edited my question and tried to make it clearer, hope it helped. how can I get the current module directory?

Comment: you have runed into permission error cos u have no write permissions to this directory. where in your pc u are trying to write? are u admin on this pc ?

Comment: for getting the curent working directory you can use the `os.getcwd()` method.

Comment: Would it return the path of the module it is called from? or the path of the script that currently executes?

Comment: it return the system path! by default where your shell is localised (the shell you are executing the py script in)